# How to close an experiment in Google Website Optimizer?

Tags: google-workspace

I am using [Google Website Optimizer](http://www.google.com/websiteoptimizer), which lets you set up multi-variant and split tests for your website to test different ideas and see which convert better.

OK so I have a test. It has been running for 4 months. I want to kill it.

I select it, go to settings and click "stop".

I am taken to a page and given 2 options:

1. help me create a follow-up
   experiment with the original and a
   top performing page variation from
   this experiment
2. choose the original or another page
   variation to continue running

I do not want either of these options, I just want to stop the experiment. It seems to be wanting to force me to continue testing on this page.

Is there a way to just kill the experiment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose option 2. It's simply asking you to choose which variation the page should show until you get around to making the appropriate changes to the page and removing the GWO code, but will not continue testing or gathering data.

Comment: Ahh, I thought it meant continue running as "continue testing."